# Program stops with error when starting executable

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a running kivy-app which works fine when I start it from vscode. But when I try to make an exe-file with

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icons/levermannApp.ico --exclude-module matplotlib LevermannApp.py
```

And then start the program I get this error message

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "kivy\core\__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
  File "kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
  File "kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
  File "kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 311, in create_window
  File "kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1268, in create_window
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 783, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__
  File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 561, in __init__
  File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 754, in _set_filename
  File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 460, in load
  File "kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 223, in __init__
  File "kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 47, in load

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "LevermannApp.py", line 28, in <module>
     class MyLayout(Widget):
   File "LevermannApp.py", line 29, in MyLayout
     Window.size = (550, 700)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
[49080] Failed to execute script LevermannApp
```

Part of my code looks like this:

```
class MyLayout(Widget):
    Window.size = (550, 700)

class LevermannScore(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LevermannScore().run()
```

My spec-file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['LevermannApp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Polzi\\Documents\\DEV\\Python-Private'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['matplotlib'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='LevermannApp',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='icons\\levermannApp.ico')
```

Any ideas why the program is running fine with vscode but not as executable?
(In the past I already was able to make an exe-file with pyinstaller for this program - but now I try it again and get the above error...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think finally i was able to solve it py defining the spec-file as following:

```
# -*- mode: python -*- 
 
import os
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
 
spec_root = os.path.abspath(SPECPATH)
block_cipher = None
app_name = 'LevermannApp'
win_icon = 'icons/levermannApp.ico'
 
a = Analysis(['LevermannApp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Polzi\\Documents\\DEV\\Python-Private'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[('*.kv', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name=app_name,
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=False,
          icon=win_icon)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name=app_name)
```

And then start simply the compilation with the command

```
pyinstaller LevermannApp.spec
```

By the way with this it is not compiled into a single exe-file (which i have normaly when using pyinstaller) - but this is no big problem for me and the exe-file is working fine.
(i will use it together with Inno Setup to compile it finally to a setup.exe)